# face 3D modelling

Tags: 3d, rendering, volume

I would like to construct 3d model from 2D face image. Please suggest some good website which can teach me step by step process

Comment: What you're asking for is nothing trivial, not even close. You should do some heavy research on image recognition, specifically creation of height maps from 2d images, and how to render those height maps... Once you have a decent knowledge of those areas you should come back with more specific questions. What you want to do is not a simple problem, and you should expect to spend some months taking care of that. Alternatively, try to find pre-built libraries or programms that do that for you.

Comment: Did you tried anything???or atleast googled it??? and which language you are prefering to implement this?